# Use AppleScript to search for message by subject

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email, reminders

Does Applescript provide a mechanism for me to search for a message by subject; or do I have to write a loop and examine every message "by hand".

The code below generates this error:  `Mail got an error: Can’t get subject of mailbox.`

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set snoozeList to "Snooze"
    set notCompleted to reminders in list snoozeList whose completed is false
    set numNotCompleted to (count of notCompleted)
    repeat with index from 1 to numNotCompleted
        set reminderName to name of item index of notCompleted
        tell application "Mail"
            set theMailbox to mailbox "Snooze" of account "GVSU"
            set foundIt to (message in theMailbox whose subject is reminderName)
            display dialog read status of message foundIt
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

The error message suggests that `whose` is being applied to the mailbox and not the messages; but, I can't figure out how to rephrase that line of code.

(For context, I would like to write a script that will iterate over all Reminders and move the linked email from the "Snoozed" folder back to the inbox.  First, however, I have to figure out how to get a reference to the linked email.)

Comment: Try: `(every message in theMailbox whose subject is reminderName)`

Comment: Yes.  Well, almost.  Your suggestion returned a list. When I took the first element of that list, everything worked as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: In that case, `first message in theMailbox whose...`, though this will throw an error if it can't find a message satisfying the criterion, whereas `every message` will return an empty list.

Comment: @CJK Could this be used as a boolean if you search for message-id? If it is empty, this message doesn't exist?

Comment: @d-b Yes, but it will be very slow to search a reasonably-sized mailbox for a `message id`. To retrieve a specific email, it would be much faster to have stored the `id` property of the message with or without the `message id` property. `message id` is limited to use in a **`whose`** filter clause, e.g. `set M to a reference to the inbox's first message whose message id = "..."`. To check: `if M exists then...` (slow!). `id` gives *direct* access to a message (so no searching), i.e. `set M to a reference to «class mssg» id 74760 in the inbox`, then checking: `if M exists then...` is instant!

Comment: @d-b [ **NB.** _The "small" caveat is Apple's idiotic use of the term `message id` as a property belonging to a `message` class object, which then means you can't reference `message` class objects by their `id` using regular nomenclature, which **should** be `get message id 74760 in the inbox`...spot the problem ? So you have to use raw syntax to reference the `message` class object, which is `«class mssg»`, and then do it in a way so that Script Editor's parser doesn't expand it back into the term `message`._ ]

Comment: @CJK I am not sure I am following you here. Is your example `74760` a UUID RFCC822 message ID or is it something like Mail.app's internal serial number for a specific message?

Comment: @CJK  I don't spot the problem and I don't know what "raw syntax" is. Care to elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: @d-b Sorry for the late reply. Open _Mail_, and select a single message. Open _Script Editor_ and execute the following: **`tell app "Mail" to tell the first item in (get selection) to return its properties`** Examine the output in detail and that will make things clearer. But to answer your question, `74760` is an integer assigned by the _Mail_ app to a specific message (the integer itself will vary from message-to-message). It is held in the `id` property. The `message id` property, however, holds a UUID RFCC822 message ID. _Raw syntax_ was exemplified in the same sentence I used the term.